# Remove all files with a given extension using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delete-file

I have some csv.crc files generated when I try to write a dataframe into a csv file using spark. Therefore I want to delete all files with .csv.crc extension

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(existingSparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val srcPath=new Path("./src/main/resources/myDirectory/*.csv.crc")
    println(fs.exists(srcPath))
    println(fs.isFile(srcPath))
    if(fs.exists(srcPath) && fs.isFile(srcPath)) {
      fs.delete(srcPath,true)
    }
```

both prinln lines give false as the value. therefor its not even going into the if condition. How can I delete all.csv.crc files using scala and spark

Answer (score 0):

You can use below option to avoid crc file while writing.(Note :you're eliminating checksum).
`fs.setVerifyChecksum(false)`.
else you can avoid crc files while reading using below,
`config.("dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.skip.checksum", "true")`.